# how to parse a string in to date,excluding time

Tags: java

i want to parse a string into date having the below code, but output contains time also.
I don't want time in my output, I just want date.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
String givendate="2013-09-09"; 
Date date=(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(givendate));
System.out.println(date);
}
```

Output of the program-: `Mon Sep 09 00:00:00 IST 2013`

Comment: You didn't format the output.

Comment: Date is a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, it has no concept of a format. Date#toString simply dumps informational output about the contents of the Date Object.  You can't remove the time from a Date object any more then you can remove the Date, but you can format it, try using the same or new formatter that meets you needs to change the way that the Date is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same formatter when printing:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));
```

implicitely a `Date` object contains time too.

Comment: I would think it contains time. What you should say is _Date contains a default format_.

Comment: sir i dont wanna print it.i want to parse it and wanna put parse result in to text field.when i use three abbreviations of "M"("yyyy-MMM-dd") it shows error Exception in thread "main"       java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-09-09"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)

Comment: when i use two "M" abbreviations it parses but output contains time too....output of program when two "M" abbreviations used- Mon Sep 09 00:00:00 IST 2013

Comment: @user2281498 A text field contains a `String`, so you will need to use `SimpleDateFormat#format()` to convert your `Date` to a `String`. If you simply `System.out.println(date)`, you will get a _default_ format for the date, which includes the time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when printing you are invoking the default format for printing the date object which includes time. Check out this link for the various formatting options

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use Joda Time

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```